# Different Layouts to support different screens in android

Tags: android, android-screen-support

When I use different layouts to support different screens , should I use  dp or px .

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12976956/450534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use dp instead of px. 
There are three distinct but linked concepts to understand here: screen density (pixels per inch/centimeter, or commonly known as DPI from dots per inch in printers), physical screen size (in inches or centimeters) and number of pixels (also known as resolution, in pixels).

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638202/android-multiple-screen-sizes-with-same-density) is entire answer. Also read [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Answer (score 1):

dp is best because it adjust itself according to the screen size of the device.It varies from device to device but less then pixel.So, always go for dp.